# NHibernate concurrent update issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I’m currently testing concurrent update situations for my c#/NHibernate application.
In the hibernate-configuration `command_timeout` is set 1 second for testing purposes. 
I use the hibernate `version` in the mapping file.

Here is the code for testing:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyHibernateConnector hc = new MyHibernateConnector(); // 1 usage see below; also provides some other hibernate related methods
            MyHibernateConfig myhibconfig = new MyHibernateConfig(); // reads and holds hibernate configuration
            hc.setHibernateConfig(myhibconfig);

            ISession session = hc.getSessionAndStartTransaction();
            // getSessionAndStartTransaction() does the following:
            // - on first call: reads the hibernate configuration and builds the SessionFactory
            // - gets the session as follows:
            //   ISession session;
            //   if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sf))
            //   {
            //       session = sf.GetCurrentSession();
            //   }
            //   else
            //   {
            //       session = sf.OpenSession();
            //       CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
            //   }
            // - and does session.BeginTransaction();

            MyClass obj;
            IQuery q = session.CreateQuery("select mc from MyClass as mc where mc.ID = ?");
            q.SetInt64(0, 60);

            l = q.List<MyClass>();
            if (l.Count > 0)
                obj = l[0];

            session.Transaction.Rollback();

            // now update obj in another application with autocommit off and do not commit or rollback

/* breakpont is set here */            session = hc.getSessionAndStartTransaction();

            try
            {
                session.Lock(obj, LockMode.Upgrade);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    session.Transaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception e2)
                {
                    Type t = e2.GetType();
                }
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

On `session.Lock(obj, LockMode.Upgrade)` an exception (`GenericADOException`) is thrown as expected with message:

```
could not lock: … for update
```

If I now catch this exception and try to do an `ISession.Transaction.Rollback()` a `TransactionException` is thrown.

I would have expected that a rollback is the appropriate action to resolve concurrent update situations. Is this not so ? And what would be the appropriate action ? What is the state of the transaction after the TransactionException ?

I use NHibernate version 5.1.0.0 and MySql.Data version 6.10.7.0. Hibernate property `dialect` is `NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL55InnoDBDialect`.

Comment: Is there any more detail regarding the `TransactionException`? Maybe in the `InnerException`?

Comment: see my EDIT in the original post. Thanks anyway for your comment.

Comment: sorry - removed my EDIT - was a "wrong" solution - will soon provide details to InnerException ...

Comment: InnerException = {"Connection must be valid and open to rollback transaction"}

Comment: **Remark**: When I do not lock the Object in the other application then the test program runs without exceptions.

Comment: Take a look at the last example in this bit of their documentation (http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-disconnection). They're using a transaction on its own rather than via the `session`. It could be that the `session`'s being set to an invalid state after the exception, but the transaction could still be usable.

Comment: @David Osborne: I did as you recommended, but the result is the same. The difference is that the documentation example uses `LockMode.Read` while I use `LockMode.Upgrade`. I use this to make sure to get hold of obj for later update and that no other (long running) transaction has updated the object and not yet commited.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting I think I found a solution - or should I better say a workaround:
The `ISession.Connection` is closed after timeout occured on `session.Lock(obj, LockMode.Upgrade)`, so open it again before the rollback:

```
if (session.Connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) // <- !!!
    session.Connection.Open();
session.Transaction.Rollback();
```

This works and I could do further transactions with the same session.

Why the connection is closed in the first place remains a mystery to me!

And I wonder if this behaviour is common to other (all?) underlying DBMS and/or drivers.